# how to remove force close error in android code

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.app123;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText input;
    EditText output;
    Button one;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == one) {
                    Context context1 = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text1 = "Please enter a valid number";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context1, text1,
                            duration);
                    toast.show();
                    int inputValue = Integer.parseInt(input.getText()
                            .toString());
                    int value = inputValue * inputValue;
                    output.setText(value);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it ispresent.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line you getting error?

Comment: Why are you using `v==one` code again?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the wiki, Have look at http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx , will help you to get the answers.

Answer (score 0):

hi remove this condition in your button click code  if(v==one) only use this like

```
        input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Context context1 = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text1 = "Please enter a valid number";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context1, text1,
                        duration);
                toast.show();
                int inputValue = Integer.parseInt(input.getText()
                        .toString());
                int value = inputValue * inputValue;
                output.setText(value);

        }
    });
```

i hope it's work for you.

Comment: you are direct use button click event using btnobj.setonclicklistener in android, so why are you check click view is button object?it work or not please reply .

Comment: Yes.. no need that condition but if there is condition I don't think so it will throw error....

Comment: hi , please change this in button click like that  output.setText(value) to  output.setText(String.valueOf(value));

Comment: i don't now but now it,s runing remove condition and set the output.setText(String.valueOf(value)) now it's runing thnks to all of you

Comment: you are direct set int value to textview text so it's create error for this line

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple buttons:

```
Button b1=(Button)findviewById(R.id.b1);
Button b2=(Button)findviewById(R.id.b2);
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getid())
            case R.id.b1:
                CharSequence text1 = "Please enter a valid number";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, text1,
                        duration);
                toast.show();
                int inputValue = Integer.parseInt(input.getText()
                        .toString());
                int value = inputValue * inputValue;
                output.setText(value);
            break;
            case R.id.b1:
            break;
        }
    });
```